# How to display UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark when setEditing is ON?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm trying to use a UITableView with some cells having the 'delete' option which is available when setEditing is set to YES, and the other cells in the table not having this option. This works great. However, there is another section of my table that I want to be able to have UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark--but being in the edit mode seems to hide this. Is there a way to display this accessory when in the edit mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `hidesAccessoryWhenEditing` was deprecated in 3.0, use the `UITableViewCell`'s `editingAccessoryType` property like so:

`[cell setEditingAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];` or
`cell.editingAccessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;`

or the appropriate accessory type to suit your needs.

Source: [Deprecated UITableViewCell Methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/hidesAccessoryWhenEditing)